# Devise not creating or updating users after sha512 encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Inherited this code base a month ago now. I pushed to a stage env only to find that User cannot be created or updated. I believe this is a related to a change before I start when sha512 was introduced.

Devise has been a thorn in my side when stuff breaks. How can I go about debugging this. I see nothing the pow applog. I have been putting logger.info everywhere but I have not found anything.

I'm not really sure what code I could include that would help you help me. I guess I'm hoping someone can help me debug devise in general as well as possibility have done this before.

Comment: So you're not getting an error just a standard rollback when a user can't be created or modified?

Comment: When I try to create a user there is no error. The form does nothing. When I edit a user a flash message comes up "Please address the following errors" but there are no errors listed or fields highlighted.

Comment: Can you create a user in the console?

Comment: Nope 1.9.2-p320 :007 > test = User.new :email => 'test@test.com', :password => 'Password1', :password_confirmation => 'Password1', :appear_in_searches => 'true', :last_name => 'test', :first_name => 'test', :secret_question => 'test', :secret_question_answer => 'test'
1.9.2-p320 :008'> test
1.9.2-p320 :009'> puts test
1.9.2-p320 :010'>